# Adding two unsigned char variables and result is int

Tags: c++

There is code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  unsigned char a = 4, b = 255;
  int g = (unsigned char)a + (unsigned char)b;
  std::cout << g << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
259
```

Why the result is 259, not 3? If there are added two unsigned char variables, there should be overflow, result should be 3 and then it should convert from unsigned char 3 to int 3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The addition operation will first [promote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer-promotion) its operands to `int`, before doing the addition. This is how C works. If you want to truncate, you need to assign it back into a narrower type, such as `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 12):

Integer arithmetic is never performed on data types smaller than `int`. For example, for types smaller than `int` e.g. if two types `char` and `short int` are added, they are promoted to `int` before any arithmetic operation and result is an integer type. If one of the types happened to be larger than int e.g `long long int` and `int` then int gets promoted to `long long int` and the result is `long long int`.

> (§ 4.5/1) - An rvalue of type char, signed char, unsigned char, short
>   int, or unsigned short
>       int can be converted to an rvalue of type int if int can represent
>   all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source rvalue can be
>   converted to an rvalue of type unsigned int.