# What should be the result of multiplication of two characters in C++?

Tags: c++

According to the C++ conversion rules, If for example an int is multiplied by a double then both will be first converted into doubles then the multiplication will be done.

```
int a = 5;
double b = 0.5;
cout<< a * b; // 2.5
```

On the other hand, multiplying an int by an int doesn't require converting and the multiplication can be done immediately resulting in an int.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 5;
cout<< a * b; //25
```

Applying the these rule, I thought that multiplying a char by a char won't require converting and the multiplication will result in a char (1 byte).
Thus, the result will overflow for the following sample

```
char a = 'a'; // 97
char b = 'b'; // 98
cout<< a * b; // 9506 - Doesn't overflow!
```

However, this doesn't seem to be the case!
Is there something special about multiplying two characters?.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538448/adding-two-unsigned-char-variables-and-result-is-int) is pretty similar. Does it give you your answer?

Comment: @chris Yes, it does.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530754/type-of-char-multiply-by-another-char) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a char by a char won't require casting and the multiplication will result in a char (1 byte).

no, *char* is automatically promoted to *int* or *unsigned int*

so in

> ```
> char a = 'a'; // 97
> char b = 'b'; // 98
> cout<< a * b; // 9506 - Doesn't overflow!
> ```

there is no overflow while an *int* as at least 14 bits, 97 and 98 are promoted from *char* in positive *int* whatever the fact a *char* is signed or not while a *char* has more than 7 bits. So you compute `97*98` being 9506

Comment: Sidenote: `int` has a Standard-mandated minimum size of 16 bits .